# R how to subset a list use another list

Tags: r, list, subset

I have two lists, and I want to subset listA by using listB.
Let's say I have listA and ListB, I want listC.

```
listA <- list(a = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10), 
           b = data.frame(x = 4:8, y = 7:11))

> listA
$a
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5  10
$b
  x  y
1 4  7
2 5  8
3 6  9
4 7  10
5 8  11

listB <- list(a = c(3,5), b = c(4, 7))
```

I want listC should be:

```
> listC
$a
  x  y
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5  10
$b
  x  y
1 4  7
2 5  8
3 6  9
4 7  10
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: It would be wise to tag your question with the programming language you're using.

Comment: What's the rule for making `listC`?

Comment: Is the rule that `listB` gives the indices of `listA`?

Comment: @lebelinoz Yes, indices of listA$a[ , 1]. The difference from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870937/how-to-subset-a-list-using-another-list is that I want from 3 to 5 and 4 to 7 (listB).

Comment: @mt1022 I want listB gives indices of listA. Take element a for example, I want subset a from 3 to 5 (column x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use `mapply`. Try this:

```
fun <- function(df, sq) df[df$x %in% seq(sq[1], sq[2]), ]
listC <- mapply(fun, listA, listB, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
listC
```

This gives

```
> listC
$a
  x  y
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10

$b
  x  y
1 4  7
2 5  8
3 6  9
4 7 10
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Save my day! @Shaun Wilkinson